# R how to do a for loop and multiply each row in a specific matrix to a column (and they display results)?

Tags: r, vector, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Let's say I have matrix a which is 10x10 (10 rows) and matrix b which is 10x1 (column)

and I want to multiply each row of a with b, so the end result would be a column of 10 elements.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(a)) a[i,] %*% b[,1]
```

I have something like the above right now

1) Is this correct?
2) How do I get it to display on screen?

Thank you, please keep in mind I'm a beginner with R. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close! In this case, you can simply do

```
c <- a %*% b
```

The operator `%*%` *is* actual matrix multiplication. For more on this consult the help page using

```
?`%*%`
```